# How to bind a model to a request in unit tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am struggling to bind a model to the request in a unit test so that the relationship of the model can be retrieved in the form request.

This is the form request:

```php
class TimeSlotUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'time' => [
                'required', 'string', 'max:50',
                Rule::unique('time_slots')
                    ->where('schedule_id', $this->timeSlot->schedule->id)
                    ->ignore($this->timeSlot),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the test (The `assertExactValidationRules` comes from Jason McCreary's Laravel test assertions package):

```php
/** @test **/
public function it_verifies_the_validation_rules(): void
{
    $timeSlot = TimeSlot::factory()->create();

    $request = TimeSlotUpdateRequest::create(
        route('admin.timeSlots.update', $timeSlot),
        'PATCH'
    )
        ->setContainer($this->app);

    $request->setRouteResolver(function () use ($request) {
        return Route::getRoutes()->match($request);
    });

    $this->assertExactValidationRules([
        'time' => [
            'required', 'string', 'max:50',
            Rule::unique('time_slots')
                ->where('schedule_id', $timeSlot->schedule->id)
                ->ignore($timeSlot->id),
        ],
    ], $request->rules());
}
```

The test passes when the where clause is removed from the test and form request but fails with the where clause with the error `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'schedule' of non-object`

I tried to step through a request with xDebug but still don't understand how to route model binding is done.

How can the `$timeSlot` model be bound request or route so that the `schedule` relationship is accessible in the form request?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Route Model Binding is handled via a middleware, the `SubstituteBindings` middleware. So the request would have to pass through the middleware stack. Since you are not doing that I suppose you could set the parameter on the route yourself:

```
$route->setParameter($name, $value);
```

`$route` would be the route object returned from `match`.

Also when dealing with a Request, if you want a route parameter you should be explicit about it and not use the dynamic property as it will return an input before it falls back to returning a route parameter:

```
$this->route('timeSlot');
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the route parameter tip too 

Comment: I am not sure if anybody can understand what the answer states. answer should have the whole code i guess. doesnt make sense to me